# Difference Asp.net Forms and None Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking for difference between forms and none authentication in asp.net, as I didn't find enough content to clarify it, so need help.

Answer (score 2):

**Forms Authentication**

A login page is defined [loginUrl=], where a user is presented with a username/password challenge.  The login page accepts the username and password, which is then used to authenticate the users against a membership database.  Authentication mechanisms include:

- Integrated: Authenticates against an Active Directory store
- ASP.NET Membership:  A SQL script provided with ASP.NET may be used to create a set of tables in a database that maintains user information.  The ASP.NET Membership provider is based on a set of interfaces, so the default implementation may be replaced with a custom implementation.  This allows you to use tables other than the "stock" membership tables created by the script.

The username/password goes over the wire unencrypted unless an SSL connection is used.  A cookie is returned on authentication to persist the login.

**No Authentication**

When authentication=none, there is no authentication performed at the IIS/ASP.NET level.  Anonymous users have full access to the content, unless a subdirectory is configured with another web.config file that has different settings.  Each subdirectory in an ASP.NET site may be configured with an independent web.config that can be used to override the root settings.

Comment: Dear Dave, Thanks for response, but I need more clarification from you. Thing is even if we use authentication=none in web.config file then also we create our own web login form and similarily with authenticatin=form, so what chanage both of this will bring to my login forms.

Comment: @Ashish:  You can still implement your own login form, but the web.config [forms] setting will automatically prevent users from accessing pages in your site (other than the login page specified in [loginUrl=]) if the user is not authenticated.  For example, if I bookmark a page deep in your site, then go back to that bookmark, the forms authentication mechanism will automatically redirect me to the login page (if my cookie is expired.)  Once I login, I'm automatically redirected to the page I requested.

Comment: @DaveSwersky Then there is still no difference, because we detect no cookie, and redirect them regardless.